# Start Java WebStart with procrun

Tags: java, windows-services, java-web-start, procrun

I'm trying to launch a Java WebStart application as a Windows Service using `procrun`. In order to do this, I created a small Java application which only launches the Java WebStart using `ProcessBuilder`. If I run this application directly, I don't have any problems and the Java WebStart is started too. If I run this application configured as Windows service using `procrun`, nothing happened. The procrun logs show me that nothing bad happened but the Java WebStart is not launched (no UI seen and no request on the servers from JavaWS).

I'm wondering if it is possible to do what I'm trying to achieve and if there is alternative ways to do it?

My goal is to launch a small Java application which uses JMS and somes Swing UI using JavaWS and start it as a Windows Service (it must be always started in the system).